# Method to contain rectangle on screen not working

Tags: methods, processing

I am trying to make a game in processing and have made a method to keep the rectangle on the screen - contain it within the window.

The method is batOnScreen()

I can't see an issue either with the maths of the method or the implementation of the method. I've (tried) to use half the height of the bat to meet the top or bottom of the screen and stop the bat moving.

The bat will stop moving when I press and release the 'w' or 's' keys but when I keep the button pressed the bat can move off of the screen. I have the method(s) working correctly when the mouse controls the bat.

Thank you

```java
    float x, y, w, h;
    float speedX, speedY; 
    float batX, batY;
    int batWidth, batHeight, batSpeed;
    boolean north, south;


    void setup() {

      size (500, 500);

      x = width / 2;
      y = height / 2;
      w = 50;
      h = 50;

      speedX = 2; // music speed?
      speedY = 4;

      batX = 30; // position
      batY = height/2;
      batWidth = 25; //bat size
      batHeight = 100;
      batSpeed = 5;
      rectMode(CENTER); //draw bat from centre
    }

    void draw() {
      background (0); // remove trail

      drawEllipse();
      bounceEllipse();
      edgeBounce();

      drawBat();
      moveBat();
      batOnScreen();
    }

    // methods 

    void drawBat() {
      fill(255, 255, 255);
      rect(batX, batY, batWidth, batHeight);
    }

    void moveBat() { // bat control
      if (north = true) {
        batY = batY - batSpeed;
      }
      if (south = true) {
        batY = batY + batSpeed;
      }
    }

    void batOnScreen() {
      if (batY - batHeight / 2 < 0) {
        batY = batY + batSpeed;
      }
      if (batY + batHeight / 2 > height) {
        batY = batY - batSpeed;
      }
    }


    void drawEllipse() {
      fill (0, 255, 0);
      ellipse(x, y, w, h);  //smaller circle than 50
    }

    void bounceEllipse() {
      x = x + speedX; // move ball X
      y = y + speedY; // move ball y
    }

    void edgeBounce() {
      //if (x > width) //bound overlap
      if (x > width - w/2) { 
        speedX = -speedX;
      } else if (x < 0 + w/ 2) {
        speedX = -speedX;
      }
      if ( y > height - h / 2) {
        speedY = -speedY;
      } else if ( y < 0 + h / 2) {
        speedY = -speedY;
      }
    }

    // bat control

    void keyPressed() {
      if (key == 'w' || key =='W') {
        batY = batY - 30;
      } else if (key == 's' || key == 'S') {
        batY = batY + 30;
      }
    }
void keyReleased() {
  if (key == 'w' || key == 'W') {
    north = false;
  }
  if (key == 's' || key == 'S') {
    south = false;
  }
}
// bat control mouse
void mouseMoved() {
  batY = mouseY;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `keyPressed()` function, you're always moving the rectangle no matter what. You never check the position to make sure it stays on the screen.

You have a bunch of different functions for moving and checking the position of the rectangle. My advice is to get rid of them and consolidate your logic in one place.

You probably want to use your `north` and `south` variables to keep track of which keys are being pressed, as outlined in [this tutorial](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/input). (See the **Handling Multiple Keys** section.)

Also, please note that this is probably not what you want to do:

```
 if (north = true) {
   batY = batY - batSpeed;
 }
 if (south = true) {
   batY = batY + batSpeed;
 }
```

This `if` statements are not doing what you think they're doing. Since you're only using a single `=` equals sign, you're assigning these values. You probably want to check equality:

```
 if (north == true) {
   batY = batY - batSpeed;
 }
 if (south == true) {
   batY = batY + batSpeed;
 }
```

And since these are `boolean` values, you could just use them directly:

```
 if (north) {
   batY = batY - batSpeed;
 }
 if (south) {
   batY = batY + batSpeed;
 }
```